# Is there any way to create a replica of Approval history using code?

Tags: approval-process, related-list

This may sound funny. But I want to create a replica of **Approval History** related list that looks exactly simillar but not include submit for **apprroval or recall button**.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding to Ashwani's answer,
You can create a new Component or VisualForce page and use ProcessInstance object and query on the object to get all approval related details. You can also include buttons to simulate approval behaviour if you want. I am pasting a small SOQL query which I used in one of my projects to give you some idea.

> SELECT Id,ProcessDefinition.Name, (SELECT Id, StepStatus, Actor.Name,
>   Comments, CreatedDate FROM StepsAndWorkitems ORDER BY Id ASC) FROM
>   ProcessInstance where TargetObjectId = :recordId

This query will help you show the approval details based on a recordId. 
You can also add a new approval step etc if required.

Answer (score 1):

I posted an updated GIST with the Page and the Extension

https://gist.github.com/emoran/04696b57600e0f892ffa714c88b80a54

but basically you'll see something like this:

[image]

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can definitely make it using apex code.

Approval records are managed by Apex class [System.Approval](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_approval.htm) and saved in [ProcessInstance](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_processinstance.htm) object. This object has 3 more child objects to manage approval stuff.

So using those above class and object you can create exact replica of approval history. This is a feasible solution.

Comment: Can  you elaborate little more on that?  Like how to reference those classes from visual force page and do I need to use<apex:relatedlsit> etc?

Comment: Same as you reference other custom objects. No difference at all! @Ricky