# Is there any way to create Audit log for all the backend and Manual changes made to any record?

Tags: apex

I have got an requirement where I have to create the audit log for the custom object which captures the details of any manual changes made at record level and also the changes which have been made via the workflows, or web-service call or any trigger or batch operations. I need to capture all these changes into a new Audit Log object. I also need to capture any emails sent from the record or any out-bound message or be it any activity which can happen at record level via any of the methods.

What will be the best approach to do this thing ?

[image]

Thanks!

Comment: Are you looking for an existing tool to do this or suggestions on how to create a tool of your own to do this? Is it important to know by what means a change was made? DML is DML regardless of whether it's via a trigger, web-service call, workflow or batch operation. Some of what you ask for are related objects (emails, activities). Field history is limited to 20 fields, do you want all fields? What form do you want to store records in?

Comment: @crmprogdev

I am not looking for an existing tool. Instead I have to write some custom code to achieve this. It is not important to by what means a change was made , its just important to know what change was made. Yes you are correct that some things are of related objects and even those needs to be tracked. and I want to track field history of all the fields. This I was able to do via trigger but then I was asked to even track the emails sent, webservices etc whatever we can think of which can be related to a record change. I have put a snip of a kind of record which I need. Thanks!

Comment: @markpond, crop1645, Chris Duncombe, bachovski, vamsi krishna

Request you to please not to put this on hold. If you want to know that what exactly I need then please post a comment and I will be happy to answer it. I know this is broad question that is why I have asked the possible ways to do it coz I am not aware of them. Please let me know what are your questions from me and help me out with this requirement. Thanks!

Comment: Are you currently tracking related tasks? Email would need to contain the WhatID of the object or be associated with an Activity plus presumable sent via Salesforce's email system or copied to it. An approach for getting some of this could be taken that's similar to the answers to http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/88213/is-there-any-way-to-create-a-replica-of-approval-history-using-code, either that or using a schedulable class to collect it as opposed to triggers on all of the different objects. I think you can ignore web services as DML is still DML.

Comment: @crmprogdev
We are not tracking related tasks yet. I have posted another question related to this http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/88257/can-we-insert-any-records-in-overloaded-methods. Can this be achieved somehow? My clients have suggested his approach.

Comment: I can't say I'd recommend the approach you've linked to. I think you're better off using a related list. Otherwise, you'd need triggers on Tasks, Events (if you use them) and Email. A scheduable or batch class that runs serially (the end of each run kicks of the next) would seem to me to be more effective in collecting the data.

Comment: @crmprogdev

Hi crmprogdev....I appreciate and thank you for all your suggestions. I will discuss all your suggested possible ways with my client and will check what will the best approach to do it. Thanks once again.
Do you have any chat room where I can discuss this requirement more with you if required ?

Comment: Chat can be reached by clicking on StackExchange drop-down at top of page. Is under Current Community as 1st item to the right of Salesforce. Send an @ to me and I'll receive notification.