# Can we insert any records in overloaded methods?

Tags: apex, class, global-methods

I have got a requirement which I have mentioned [**here**](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/88256/is-there-any-way-to-create-audit-log-for-all-the-backend-and-manual-changes-made)

I have been asked to create some overloaded methods to achieve this. Something like below.

```
Public Class OverloadedClass
{
    Public Static Void OverloadedMethod(Object1__c Obj1Id, String Event Name)
    {
    }

    Public Static Void OverloadedMethod(Object1__c Obj1Id, Object2__c Obj2Id, String Event Name)
    {
    }

    Public Static Void OverloadedMethod(Object1__c Obj1Id, Object2__c Obj2Id, String Event Name, User UserId, String EventNotes)
    {
     //Here in this last method I have to insert records in my Audit Log object something like below. Can this be done somehow ??
        for(Apttus_Proposal_Proposal__c APP : ProposalIds)
        {            
        Price_Driver_Audit_Log__c PDAL1 = new Price_Driver_Audit_Log__c();

        PDAL1.Object1__c = APP1.Obj1Id;
        PDAL1.Object2__c = APP1.Obj2Id;
        PDAL1.Audit_Event_Name__c = 'New Object1 record Created';
        PDAL1.Audit_Event_Notes__c = 'A new Object1 record has been created';
        PDAL1.User__c = APP1.lastmodifiedbyId;
        PDALList1.add(PDAL1); 
    }}
}
```

Can this be achieved somehow ?

Thanks!

Comment: There are all sorts of issues with what you have: (1) `PDAList1` and `APP1` and not declared; (2) variable names `obj1Id` and `obj2Id` imply they are IDs but are of type `Object1__c` and `Object2__c`, resp. and (3) the first two methods never call the third method with nulls or defaults for the missing/additional parameters.

Comment: @crop1645
I have mentioned the above code just as an example to show what I am asked to do. I have not tried this approach yet as I am not aware how to do it. I have to make few overloaded methods from which I have to pass all the values to the last method and insert the audit log records. Is this achievable ?

Answer (score 1):

Well, I'm not 100% certain of your requirements but writing overloaded methods can be achieved as follows ( I made some liberal assumptions about what you are trying to do business logic-wise):

```
Public Class OverloadedClass {
Public Static Void OverloadedMethod(Apttus_Proposal_Proposal__c[] appList,
        Id Obj1Id, String EventName) {
    log(appList, obj1Id, null, eventName, null, null);
}

Public Static Void OverloadedMethod(Apttus_Proposal_Proposal__c[] appList,
         Id Obj1Id, ID Obj2Id, String EventName) {
    log(appList, obj1Id, obj2Id, eventName, null, null);
}

Public Static Void OverloadedMethod(Apttus_Proposal_Proposal__c[] appList, 
         ID Obj1Id, ID Obj2Id, String EventName, ID UserId, String EventNotes) {
    log(appList, obj1Id, obj2Id, eventName, userId, eventNotes);
}

// Common worker method for each entry point
private static void log(Apttus_Proposal_Proposal__c[] appList, 
         ID Obj1Id, ID Obj2Id, String EventName, ID UserId, String EventNotes) {

    Price_Driver_Audit_Log__c[] pdalList = new Price_Driver_Audit_Log__c();
    for(Apttus_Proposal_Proposal__c APP : Proposals) {

      Price_Driver_Audit_Log__c PDAL = new Price_Driver_Audit_Log__c(
            object1__c = obj1Id,
            object2__c = obj2Id,
            Audit_Event_Name__c = eventName != null 
              ? eventName : 'New Object1 record Created',
            Audit_Event_Notes__c = eventNotes != null 
              ? eventNotes : 'A new Object1 record has been created',
            User__c = userId != null ? userId : APP.lastmodifiedbyId);
      pdalList.add(PDAL); 
    }
    insert pdalList;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions. I'll try to implement this and see if this works out for me. Thanks!

Answer (score -2):

I have read your requirement on the link given by you. We can do it by using a **Trigger on AFTER INSERT**.
In the code of this trigger you can write some code to insert a new record in your new custom object for storing Audit Log.

Using a trigger in your case would be the best solution of it.

Comment: I did this by trigger already before but we cannot track all the changes by it...like the email sent from the record. And I am doubtful if we can track changes made by webservice calls. Can all this be done by trigger ?